# data Table on JSF + PrimeFaces

Tags: java, html, jsf-2, primefaces

I need some help because I need to create dynamically tables in my page and for this I use 
ui:repeat tag.
Here is my code in the jsf file:

```
<ui:define name="contenido">
    <p:fieldset legend="Cronograma">
        <ui:repeat value="#{cronogramaBean.cronogramaBB.listaParciales}" var="parciales">
            <br/>
            <p:dataTable id="tablaPacial"
                         value="#{**here I want to use the same item in the list that I use in the Ui:repeat**}"
                         var="parcial"
                         emptyMessage="No existen registros"
                         rows="10"
                         rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                         sortBy="#{parcial.ordinal}"  sortOrder="ascending"
                         style="overflow: auto">
                <f:facet name="header">  
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{parcial.ciclo.nombre}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="Nº"
                          style="text-align: center; width: 20px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Nombre"
                          style="width: 100px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{parcial.nombre}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:fieldset>
</ui:define>
```

the ui:repat tag need's a in the value a list and a var to iterate the list, inside the ui:repeat I want to create the tables with the same list.
Is this posible?
How I can do that?

Comment: I recommend to remove irrelevant noise from your question and reformulate your question like so: "I have this JSF code [...]. I want to achieve this HTML output [...]. How can I achieve this?" That's much easier to understand. I tried editing your question into an understandable fashion, but I failed at the sentence *"inside the ui:repeat I want to create the tables but I need also a list, and I wasn't able to use the same list of the ui:repeat"*. That part was unintelligible. Code is as being an universal language much easier to understand than words.

Comment: sorry and thank you for your help I do other things to achieve what I wanted. I create a new object because I need a list inside the other list one for the repeat and another for the dataTable.

Comment: I do still not understand you. Click "edit" and improve your question based on my previous comment. "I have this JSF code [...]. I want to achieve this HTML output [...]. How can I achieve this?". Fill out the missing parts inside [...].

Comment: While it's never easy to say, "You need to work on your English before we can help you with your question" this is a perfect case of better English needed for any communication. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/the-ugly-american-programmer.html

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I hope this time you understand the question :)

Comment: I mean, you should fill [...] with pure code, not with words. As said, code is an universal language. You understand JSF and HTML code. I also understand JSF and HTML code. Show the JSF code you have. Show the desired HTML output which your JSF code should generate. E.g. `<table><tr><td>blah blah`. You're familiar with basic HTML, right? Keep it simple! For example, empty message, sort fields and styles are irrelevant to the concrete problem/question. Just leave those things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes you can use the same `value` for `ui:repeat` and `p:dataTable` **but** it will do a behavior that you don't want. All tables will have exactly the same data.

To achieve what you want, you need to change `#{cronogramaBean.cronogramaBB.listaParciales}` for a `List` of `List` example :

```
public List<List<Partial>> getListaParciales()
{

}
```

And modify your view like this :

```
<ui:define name="contenido">
    <ui:repeat value="#{cronogramaBean.cronogramaBB.listaParciales}" var="parciales">
        <p:fieldset legend="Cronograma">
            <p:dataTable id="tablaPacial"
                    value="#{parciales}"
                    var="parcial"
                    emptyMessage="No existen registros"
                    rows="10"
                    rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                    sortBy="#{parcial.ordinal}"  sortOrder="ascending"
                    style="overflow: auto">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{parcial.ciclo.nombre}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="Nº"
                        style="text-align: center; width: 20px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Nombre"
                        style="width: 100px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{parcial.nombre}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:fieldset>
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: In fact the goal is to generate multiple tables in a dynamic way....

Comment: @XavierÑauñay Have you a `List` of `List` in your bean? Ortherwise the same data will be repeated, this is what you probably don't want.

Comment: yes, I got repeated entries, Using a List of List is the only way to do this??

Comment: You need a List of List, ortherwise data in each table will be the same, so only the last one will be kept. Do you want the user to fill one table and dynamically add new ones depending on how many he needs?

Comment: no, now I am using the `List of List` option the idea was to obtain and create a table for every ciclo from the a database.
I obtain "ciclos" from the table ciclos and every ciclo has "parciales" from table parciales_inst and in parciales_inst table I dont have relation with ciclos.

Comment: So I suggest you to create a `List<Ciclo>` and your Object `Ciclo` will contain a `List<Partial`> does that make sense?

Comment: yes I create a new class with my object ciclo and a list<Parcial> and in my bean I create a list of this object(list<CiclowithListOfPartials>) now I am able to call this list in the ui:repeat and use the list inside the object on the table.